# Is there any support for drag and drop on touch devices?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

The [W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/dnd.html) doesn't explicitly use the word touch.

[This](http://blog.alaabadran.com/2012/01/23/drag-and-drop-with-jquery-for-touch-devices/) is a popular answer around the internet but

- [I can't get it to work](http://jsfiddle.net/Nf9Ak/4/)
- That code is a couple years old and partially [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createEvent?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fdocument.createEvent)

Manually converting touch events into mouse events does not work (or is too complicated +it will break in future browsers). See code below as an example:

```
myDragElement.on("touchstart", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    drag.trigger("dragstart");
});
myDragElement.on("touchmove", function (e) {
    drag.trigger("mousemove", e.originalEvent); // what event to send to .trigger? does it even matter?
});
```

What is the most native way of accomplishing drag and drop on a touch device? I can write the code manually or find a plugin but a native solution would be nice.

Comment: either native to the browser or native to core jQuery

Answer (score 1):

I have some sliders and they require to control touch, drag, etc, but some of them doesn't work properly on touch device at all since they just use the native event from HTML 5. I've found the useful plugin to handle this thing.

Try it

http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/

[GitHub Wiki](https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js)

The source has included the demo to see what event would happened when you will run it on touch device

Answer (score 0):

I had success using jQuery's HTML5 drag drop features along with Touch Punch. Give credit to roman m for recommending it.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16865205/705483