# Can Blazor drag drop work with mouse and touch with this implementation

Tags: drag-and-drop, blazor

My drag drop code is working fine with mouse, but not on a touch screen.  Should the below work or is there a mistake here?

The draggable item:

```
<div class="draggable-area" draggable="true" 
   @ondragstart="@(() => HandleDragStart())"
   @ontouchstart="@(() => HandleDragStart())">

protected async virtual Task HandleDragStart()
{
    // set the draggable object
    _draggableItem = this;
}
```

The droppable area (in a different component):

```
<div class="droppable-area"
     @ondrop="HandleDrop" 
     @ondrop:stopPropagation="true"
     ondragover="event.preventDefault();">

protected async override Task HandleDrop()
{
    // handle the drop
    Console.WriteLine($"Dropped item: {_draggableItem}");
}
```

Comment: Did you try with the right events? https://stackoverflow.com/a/3603510/842935

Comment: in terms of starting the drag, I thought I was using the right event @daniherrera ... ?

Comment: Mobiles don't use drag, they use various touch events.  I think if you want both, you'll have to implement both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I used in one of my projects is to implement drag and drop only for mouse using the [HTML Drag and Drop API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API) and then use [dragdroptouch](https://github.com/Bernardo-Castilho/dragdroptouch) polyfill to add support for touch screens. The library needs a simple modification in order to work with Blazor as discussed [here](https://github.com/Postlagerkarte/blazor-dragdrop/issues/147#issuecomment-1200308069).

Comment: Thanks -= this was exactly what was required.   I'm amazed the HTML drag drop API doesn't already cover this!